# How to convert an array of timestamps to datetime in python?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I want to convert an array of timestamps to datetime. For some reason, I can only do it in below with for loop. This makes the program slow with a lot of loops.

Any way to improve the speed?

=============

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

xx = [1.60511548e+09, 1.60511551e+09, 1.60511552e+09]

yy = [datetime.fromtimestamp(t) for t in xx]
```

Comment: Does it really? Have you benchmarked it and determined that the loops are the bottleneck? Is it significantly faster if you manually write `datetime.fromtimestamp` 3 times instead of doing it in a loop? (Hint: probably not.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply the datetime.fromtimestamp() function to any item in your xx list, the map() function is a great way.
Try `yy = list(map(datetime.fromtimestamp, xx))`.
But you have to try if this is really faster than the loop.

Comment: To be explicit: this still *loops over a list*, but might do so slightly more efficiently than a userland `for` loop. It's not *fundamentally* different though. Also note that you will have to do `list(map(...))` for true apples to apples comparison.

Comment: I agree, but on the other hand, he wants to apply that function to each item, so he has to iterate over the list the one way or the other (or am I wrong?).

Comment: Yes, exactly, so it's fundamentally unclear why OP thinks loops are the issue.

Comment: I tried and the runtime is identical. I guess this is just what it takes.

Comment: `yy = np.frompyfunc(datetime.fromtimestamp, nin=1, nout=1)(xx)`